# C# Lambda in MethodInfo invocation

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to invoke a lambda expression dynamically, but all I got is the methodInfo to do so.

Something like:

```
Magic.RegisterStaticPacketHandler<TestPacket>((a, b) => { /* Do Stuff */ });

Magic class:
public void RegisterStaticPacketHandler<T>(PacketReceivedHandler<T> handler) where T : Packet
{
            //Remember the handler with: handler.GetMethodInfo()
}
```

And later on I would like to invoke this method. Because PacketReceivedHandler is a delegate, I can get the "MethodInfo" out of it. If I invoke this MethodInfo with just:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { packet, this });
```

I ofc receive an exception, that the given object (obj) doesn't fit.
Setting BindingFlags like "NonPublic | Instance | Static" doesnt help either.

**UPDATE**

PacketReceivedHandler looks as follows:

```
public delegate void PacketReceivedHandler<T>(T packet, Connection connection) where T : Packet;
```

And I save it in my Magic class:

```
private Dictionary<int, Tuple<MethodInfo, object>> id_methodInfo_object = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<MethodInfo, object>>();
```

- MethodInfo = The delegate
- object = Where the delegate comes from
- id = UID for networking stuff

Comment: Wouldn't `Action<T>` be easier? `RegisterStaticPacketHandler<T, U>(Action<T, U> handler)` and then just do `hander([instance of T], [instance of U])`

Comment: Yeah, invoking lambdas using reflection is tricky, because they may capture a closure, and you have to supply the `Target` of the delegate

Comment: Because the generic type <T> is unknown I can't save them into a local variable. Instead of that I just save the methodInfo. So an action wouldn't help me ether. Same situation.

Comment: @TamasHegedus Target is available to me. Working with fixed methods in the code just works fine. But If I replace the method with a lambda it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to save the `Target` of the delegate besides the method. The easiest is to directly store the whole delegate itself instead of `MethodInfo`. Something like this:

```
// Store any lambda or action or anything in their baseclass "Delegate":
Delegate act = new Action<int, int>((a, b) => Console.WriteLine(a + b));

// Dynamically invoke like this:
act.Method.Invoke(act.Target, new object[] {4, 9});
```

Full example:

```
class Program
{
    private static List<Delegate> handlers = new List<Delegate>();
    public static void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> del)
    {
        handlers.Add(del);
    }
    public static void InvokeHandlers(params object[] args)
    {
        foreach (var h in handlers)
        {
            h.Method.Invoke(h.Target, args);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegisterHandler((object a) => Console.WriteLine("#1:" + a));
        RegisterHandler((object a) => Console.WriteLine("#2:" + a));
        InvokeHandlers("foo");
        InvokeHandlers(1234);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why you only store raw `Delegate`s. I included a full example to give you some idea, but to be honest, I don't really understand what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Ok, great idea. Doing so following exception occurs: "An die Zielmethode kann nicht gebunden werden, da die Signatur oder Sicherheitstransparenz nicht mit der des Delegattypen kompatibel ist"

Something like: "Cant bind to the destination method. The signature or security transparency is not compatable with the delegate"

Maybe because the delegate is public, but the lambda is anonymous?

Comment: @ThomasChristof Another idea: Just use `PacketReceivedHandler<Packet>` everywhere, it will work because of delegate covariance.

Comment: Ok, I will go for actions. Thank you very much! Was stuck at this problem since 2 days. That really helps me out.

Comment: @ThomasChristof The error means that you supplied wrong arguments to the delegate. Could you paste the definition of `PacketReceivedHandler<T>` and how you try to invoke it?

Comment: With just    PacketReceivedHandler<Packet> the programmer always has to cast to the right class. And thats something I would like to prevent.

Comment: @ThomasChristof Well, You don't have to use actions :D every delegate works the same. I used actions only because I didnt have the definition of your specific delegate type, but any delegate type would work the same!

Comment: _With just PacketReceivedHandler<Packet> the programmer always has to cast to the right class_ I don't see why would they have to.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public void RegisterStaticPacketHandler<T>(PacketReceivedHandler<T> handler) where T : Packet
{
     _methodInfo = handler.Method;
}
```

See details in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Delegate.Method);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: Yes, with handler.GetMethodInfo() or handler.Method I receive the MethodInfo. Now how do I continue? methodInfo.Invoke doesnt work for lambdas.